# JCombobox inside JTable not listening to key press

Tags: java, jtable, jcombobox

I have custom Jcombobox (not editable) inside a JTable. I clicked on the JCombobox to make the dropdwon visible and then tried changing the selected Item with Key press down/up but it is not listening to my events.

With the mouse click focus is moving to JComboBox but it is not listening to the key up/down keys to select the item from dropdown.

Appreciate if anyone can tell me why dropdown is not listening to key events or what can cause this. Thanks!

Comment: maybe you are using the wrong listener. you should post your code.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I found the problem. I have custom component as editor which is not listening my events.